# How to generate a Docker digest from a local image

Tags: docker, hash

I generated a Docker image locally and once created it appears in `docker images --digests` but without digest.

```
REPOSITORY    TAG     DIGEST   IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
exampleimage  local   <none>   e143f92ce9bc        3 minutes ago       146MB
```

How can I generate a digest for this image without uploading it to a v2 registry ?

I plan to use it in a subsequent script and upload it only if the script succeed.

Thanks.

Edit: Apparently, the digest does not depend of the registry in `v2-2` as found here [Why digests are different depend on registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45533005/why-digests-are-different-depend-on-registry#comment78038106_45535274) so it should be possible to generate it locally.

Comment: looking for this info as well - did you figure this out?

Comment: Sadly no. Sorry.

Comment: I am pushing to the registry and then reading the digest, this seems to work.

Comment: Yes, but the question is about how to have a digest without pushing to the registry first.